# java.util.<>Hashset cannot be converted to boolean

Tags: java, boolean

I have an error in this code

```
public Hotel()
{
    occupiedRooms = new HashSet<Room>();
    PapersOrdered = new HashMap <String,ArrayList<String>>();

}


 public String getGuest(String roomNo)
{
    for (Room room; occupiedRooms;)
    {
        if(room.getRoomNo().equals(roomNo))     return room; getGuest();
        return "room " + roomNo + " is not occupied" ;
    }
}
```

and the occupied rooms gets an error saying java.util.<>Hashset cannot be converted to boolean,
what is the best way to correct this.(All code is not in here but just what is relevant)

Comment: What does the `getGuest()` call do without parameters? You can probably get rid of it. You also probably want to return failure outside the `for` loop, not in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a `HashSet` is not a boolean and cannot be converted to a boolean, and the regular for loop expects a boolean expression in the middle section (the section that determines when the loop terminates).

If you want to iterate over all the values in the set, you can use the enhanced for loop :

```
for (Room room : occupiedRooms)
{
    if(room.getRoomNo().equals(roomNo))
        return room;
    getGuest();
    return "room " + roomNo + " is not occupied" ;
}
```

Not sure how much sense your for loop makes, though, as it would always return something after the first`room` is tested, so the remaining rooms won't be checked.